# How should I get the dummy columns using the Query in SQL Server (like 'select name from dual' in Oracle)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 R2.
I have designed a report which takes StartDate, EndDate, PayType as parameter values to run the report (dataset1).
These parameter values are passed from another data set query.
so I have written other query as (dataset2),

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
bb_propdt AS [Start Date],
bb_propdt AS [End Date],

CASE 
WHEN bbprop.bb_paytype = '1' THEN 'PDC' 
WHEN bbprop.bb_paytype = '2' THEN 'NoPDC' 
WHEN bbprop.bb_paytype = '3' THEN 'ECS' 
ELSE 'NA'
END AS [Pay Type] 

FROM         
bbprop
```

The problem is that, it is showing me all distinct dates, so far good.
But it is also showing me distinct pay type.
so in a parameter dropdown list I am getting number of PDC, NoPDC, ECS.
What I want is only 3 values, PDC, NoPDC, ECS.
I can use use another data set to solve this problem, but I don't want one more data set.
I was searching like

```
select PDC, NoPDC, ECS from dual;
```

In SQL Server. But there is no such thing.

Below pic will help you to get the problem easily.

[image]

This is showing me no. of dates, it is OK.

[image]

But here I want only three values as PDC, NoPDC, ECS.

Comment: don't you need separate queries for this?

Comment: Yes I can use one more dataset but I don't. So I just want any Query like "select PDC, NoPDC, ECS from dual". Or any other modification in existing query if possible.

Comment: try this:  `SELECT PDC UNION SELECT NoPDC UNION SELECT ECS`. You don't need `dual` for this. Just put `UNION` on separate line

Comment: Its not working. I tried this. I have also tried the situation with using subquery to get distinct values, but subquery is returning more than one value.

Comment: well definitely you cannot accomplish in one query, you have to have two result sets in your data-set or do something on client-side (after results are fetched, before binding the combobox) to get distinct pay-types and bind with second combo.

Comment: Ok. Thank you TheVillageIdiot. I have taken two datasets as there is no other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query to populate the Dataset:

```
select PayType = 'PDC'
union all
select PayType = 'NoPDC'
union all
select PayType = 'ECS'
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22544).

When you're setting up the parameter Available Values, point it to this Dataset for both the Value and Label.

You can also do this with a query/Dataset if it is a set of known values, just use the **Available Values** -> **Specify values** option when defining the parameter:

[image]

Comment: Yes its working. Nice one. I was searching for the dummy table. Thank You.

Comment: Cool, glad to help... I thought of another option that might be applicable - added some more details.

Comment: Yes lan. I did the same. Used the required label with appropriate value.